# show hadoop files on HDFS only created on a specific day

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to show hadoop files on HDFS under a specific folder which created on a specific day, is there a command/option to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: What's the file pattern? Use `pipeline` and `regex`?

Comment: @luoluo, what do you mean file pattern? For filename, there is no pattern on date and I just want to use a command to show only files created on a specific day, and then hadoop fs -text to show its content to analyze. Any good suggestions are appreciated. :)

Comment: As far as I know, `hadoop` command won't support this. You can write a script to achieve this, which is not a good implementation. My suggestions: organize your file in the way you would use more conveniently. Say in your case, make a time partition would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `hadoop` command won't support this.

You can write a script to achieve this, which is not a good implementation.

**My suggestions:**

1. Organize your file in the way more convenient to be used. Say in your case, make a `time partition` would be better.
2. If you want to make data analysis easier, use some `database` based on `hdfs` like [`hive`](https://hive.apache.org/). `hive` support `partition` and `sql` like query and insert.

more about `hive` and `hive partitions`:
https://hive.apache.org/
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-PartitionedTables